# Why does this simple Math.max() example return NaN?

Tags: javascript

According to the docs here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max I should be able to use an array, right?

https://jsfiddle.net/utkLh4p6/

```js
var a = [875, 551];
console.log( Math.max(a) ); // NaN
```

Comment: @user202729 - Nice catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may think you can pass an array because of the syntax:

```
Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
```

The brackets in this syntax indicate that the value is optional, not that it is a member of an array.

Comment: Ok thank you, the issue was really just my ability to read documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Math.max(...a)
```

You need to spread it.